# Illustrator's Pathfinder Divide but in Javascript for SVGs

Tags: svg, adobe-illustrator, paperjs, svgo

I am trying to automate a process I currently do in Illustrator but would like to be in the browser.  In Illustrator with vector art, I expand all text and strokes and use pathfinder divide to flatten everything.  I have come across SVGO and Paper.js and I am trying to figure out the most practical way to go about this without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show what you've already tried in paper.js etc. Converting text and strokes is tricky in js. E.g your fonts need to be embedded as data urls; you would also need a parser like opentype.js. Besides, paper.js doesn't include a stroke conversion - there is an addon - but it also struggles with some shapes. All in all an application based batch script e.g via ExtendScript API is probably more promising.

Comment: I do not have an example yet because I am trying to see if this even feasible.  That is the reason for my question really.

Comment: That's understandable. However, your current question is likely to be closed due to a lack of programming related details. So my advice would be to search for SO posts related to Adobe Illustrator automisation. You may also take advantage of inkscapes powerful CLI tools – provided your files are svg and not .ai. For further  research: I also highly  recommend  to ignore search engine results coming from support.adobe – Just test it (and read these results)  for, say, 10 times and you'll definitely understand how "helpful" these forum posts can be at the most =)

Comment: So you have SVG as input and SVG as output? Probably you can use the couple Inkscape + Python script. (Instead of Illustrator + Extendscript)